# Cloning VM causes one of the VM drives to write-protect itself

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I am creating a "sandbox" development VM for a locked-down work environment. I am working on a baseline VM, enabled as a "template", and then am testing clones to see if they work after deployment.

My guest system (a Windows 7 guest on VMWare 11 Workstation also running on a Windows 7 host) has two "drives" (VMDKs). When I make a clone of that system, the first drive - my putative 'C' drive - behaves normally - I can read/write/edit/delete files on that drive as expected. However, the secondary drive (mapped as "E:") is write protected - I cannot create files nor copy files to that drive. It is correctly formatted as an active NTFS volume (and it works fine on the baseline VM template).

I cannot get the write protection to *permanently* go away. We had a duece of a time trying to solve the problem; one of my engineers managed to find a bit of registry magic that appeared to fix the problem:

```
Set Policies\Microsoft\PVE\RDVDenyWriteAccess=dword:00000000
Set Policies\Microsoft\PVE\FDVDenyWriteAccess=dword:00000000
in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet and all other HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSetxxx hives
```

However, the resulting cloned VM will spontaneously write-protect the second drive again, with no perceivable pattern, forcing me to re-run the registry script and reboot the VM to be able to write to that drive again. This is annoying.

Can anyone tell me why this "local hard drive" started as write-protected on the clone (full clone, not linked clone) and keeps resetting itself to being write-protected? More importantly, how can I make it permanently read/write in the cloned VM the way that hard drives should behave???

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was a combination of an apparently deliberate behavior by VMWare and policies set on the locked-down copy of Windows I used to create the guest.

VMWare apparently makes all of the non-OS drives *removable* drives so they can be hot-swapped without shutting down the guest. While this may seem to be a nice idea, group policies have settings to disable reading and writing to external drives and/or force you to "bitlocker" external drives if you want to write to them. If any of these policies are enabled, they don't play well with VMWare. Once I disabled the "Removable Drive: Deny Write Access" and "Deny access to removable drives not protected by Bitlocker" policies, the bad behavior went away.